# Create the inverse of mapping

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

What is the inverse mapping of $f:{\{0,1\}}^{\{0,1\}}\mapsto{\{0,1,2,3\}}, b \mapsto b_0*2^0+b_1*2^1$ ?

For me it is not clear how I can do that with a polynom consisting more than one variable (here are two: $b_0, b_1$).

Comment: There are four elements in each set. What stops you from writing an exhaustive list of the values of $f$ at different $b$?

Comment: I do not know how I could do that... While researching I have only found explanations how to inverse polynoms with only one variable. Here are two ($b_0,b_1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $\{0,1\}^{\{0,1\}}$ are functions from $\{0,1\}$ to $\{0,1\}$, which is the same as a two-emelent sequence where the elements are either $0$ or $1$. In other words, there are the four elements $(0,0), (0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$. We have, for instance, $f(0,1) = 0\cdot 2^0 + 1\cdot 2^1 = 2$. Can you do the rest? The inverse can be described by simply listing all the elements of $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and what they are mapped to, like $2\mapsto (0,1)$.

Comment: Is $f:\{0,1,2,3\} \mapsto \{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\},(0,0) \mapsto 0, (0,1) \mapsto 2, (1,0) \mapsto 1, (1,1) \mapsto 3$ the correct inverse mapping?

Comment: No, that's the mapping. To get the inverse mapping, turn all the arrows around.